# Find $\min\int_0^\pi {f^2(x)dx}$, assume $\int_0^\pi{f(x)\sin xdx} = \int_0^\pi{f(x)\cos xdx} = 1.$

Tags: integration, inequality

$f(x)$ is continuous on $[0,\pi]$ and $\int_0^\pi{f(x)\sin xdx} = \int_0^\pi{f(x)\cos xdx} = 1.$

Find $\min\int_0^\pi {f^2(x)dx}.$

I try to solve this problem by this:
$$\begin{array}{l}
{\left( {\int\limits_0^\pi  {f(x)\sin xdx} } \right)^2} \le \left( {\int\limits_0^\pi  {{f^2}(x){{\sin }^2}xdx} } \right)\left( {\int\limits_0^\pi  {dx} } \right) \le \pi \int\limits_0^\pi  {{f^2}(x){{\sin }^2}xdx} \\
{\left( {\int\limits_0^\pi  {f(x)\cos xdx} } \right)^2} \le \pi \int\limits_0^\pi  {{f^2}(x){{\cos }^2}xdx} \\
 \Rightarrow \pi \int\limits_0^\pi  {{f^2}(x)\left( {{{\sin }^2}x + {{\cos }^2}x} \right)dx}  \ge 1 + 1 = 2
\end{array}$$
The thing is I can't find $f(x)$ to let the equation happens. Any help? Thank you in advance.

Comment: You have used CS inequality in two different places. Can you show that they can simultaneously be never equalities?

Comment: @Macavity Yes, I see that they're never equalities simultaneously. Could you show me a different way to approach this problem? Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Define
$$
 g(x) = f(x) - \frac 2\pi \sin x - \frac 2\pi \cos x \, .
$$
Then
$$
 \int_0^\pi g(x) \cos x \, dx= \int_0^\pi f(x) \cos x \, dx
 - \frac 2\pi \int_0^\pi \sin x \cos x \, dx
 - \frac 2\pi \int_0^\pi \cos^2 x \, dx \\
 = 1 - 0 - 1 = 0
$$
and similarly, 
$$
 \int_0^\pi g(x) \sin x \, dx= 0 \, .
$$
Therefore
$$
 \int_0^\pi f^2(x) = \int_0^\pi \left( g(x) + \frac 2\pi \sin x + \frac 2\pi \cos x\right)^2 \, dx \\
 =  \int_0^\pi g^2(x) \, dx + \frac{4}{\pi^2} \int_0^\pi \sin^2(x) \, dx
+ \frac{4}{\pi^2} \int_0^\pi \cos^2(x) \, dx
$$
because all integrals with the "mixed terms" from expanding the square
vanish.

It follows that
$$
\int_0^\pi f^2(x) \ge \frac{4}{\pi^2} \int_0^\pi \sin^2(x) \, dx
+ \frac{4}{\pi^2} \int_0^\pi \cos^2(x) \, dx
 = \frac 4 \pi \, .
$$
Equality holds if $g(x) = 0$, i.e. for the function
$$
 f(x) =  \frac 2\pi \sin x + \frac 2\pi \cos x \, .
$$

*(This is essentially the same proof as given by Jacky Chong, but
  without using the theory of Fourier series.)*

---

Another way to look at the problem is to consider the set of all
real-valued continuous functions on $[0, \pi]$ as 
[*inner product space*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inner_product_space)
with the scalar product 
$$
 \langle g, h \rangle = \int_0^\pi g(x)h(x) \, dx \, .
$$
What we did is to define $g$ as the *orthogonal projection* of
$f$ on the subspace spanned by $\{ \sin, \cos \}$:
$$
g = f - \frac{\langle f, \sin \rangle}{\langle \sin, \sin \rangle} \sin
 - \frac{\langle f, \cos \rangle}{\langle \cos, \cos \rangle} \cos
 = f - \frac 2 \pi \sin - \frac 2 \pi cos
$$
and concluded that
$$
 \| f \|^2 = \langle f, f \rangle = \langle g, g \rangle
+ \frac{4}{\pi^2} \langle \sin, \sin \rangle + 
 \frac{4}{\pi^2} \langle \cos, \cos \rangle
 = \| g \|^2 + \frac 4 \pi \, .
$$

Answer (score 3):

Let us consider the Fourier series of $f$
\begin{align}
f(x) = \frac{1}{2}a_0+\sum^\infty_{n=1} a_n \cos nx+ \sum^\infty_{n=1} b_n \sin nx
\end{align}
then that means
\begin{align}
\int^\pi_0 f^2(x)\ dx= \frac{1}{4}a_0^2+\frac{\pi}{2}\sum^\infty_{n=1}(a_n^2+b_n^2).
\end{align}
Since
\begin{align}
\int^\pi_0 f(x) \cos x\ dx = 1
\end{align}
then this means $a_1= 2/\pi$ and likewise $b_1 = 2/\pi$. It follows
\begin{align}
\int^\pi_0 f^2(x)\ dx \geq \frac{4}{\pi}= \frac{\pi}{2}(a_1^2+b_1^2).
\end{align}

Comment: Thanks for your short answer, and let me find out more about the Fourier series because I haven't learn about that yet.